# Spring Security: DaoAuthenticationProvider autoconfiguration with default PasswordEncoder and UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security.

I defined the following bean for `PasswordEncoder`:

```
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
```

And also I have this class implementing UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService { //... }
```

Then I defined the following bean:

```
  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
      PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return authProvider;
  }
```

I'm not doing much in the later bean definition since it is just creating a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with default `PasswordEncoder` and `UserDetailsService` beans.

My question is if there is someway to avoid the trivial definition of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` or if it is always necessary.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I'm using Basic Auth (it's a very simple use case):

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
```

Comment: we have no idea, since you have not posted your security definition, or even told us what type of authentication/authorization you are implementing. Client cert, SAML, JWT, Form Login, Session based, opague token oauth2? or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: The `DaoAuthenticationProvider` you provided is similar to what's created internally for both `http.formLogin()` and `http.httpBasic()`. Please share your security configuration. If you're following a tutorial, can you please share the link to that as well?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I updated the answer. I'm using basic auth.

Comment: @Toerktumlare No, you are not supposed to guess. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your security configuration (from the updated question), Spring Security will create an `AuthenticationManager` composed with a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` configured more or less exactly like your `@Bean`. In most cases, you do not need to specify the `@Bean` `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, and it can be removed.

In other words, yes, you can avoid the definition of the `AuthenticationProvider` by specifying the `SecurityFilterChain` `@Bean` exactly as you have done.

You would typically only expose an `AuthenticationProvider` or (more commonly) an `AuthenticationManager` defined like your example if you require the use of that component in your own application code (e.g. in a `@RestController` or an `@Service`). Normally, Spring Security will automatically use the internally built `AuthenticationManager` in the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` on your behalf.

Comment: I removed the DaoAuthenticationProvider bean configuration and it worked in the same way that not declarating the bean at all, thanks.

Comment: So can we conclude that spring boot will auto configure to instantiate the concrete class BasicAuthenticationFilter and  DaoAuthenticationProvider by default, as long as we don't define our own bean for them.

Comment: It will be autoconfigured, yes. Though I will correct you on the semantics, it's not Spring Boot doing this but Spring Security. I understand it's a gray area for most users, but knowing that Spring Boot typically only auto-configures certain `@Bean` definitions and that filters are not configured by Boot may be helpful to you.